# Finding lines without letters or numbers, only with commas, BASH

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Good day to all,

I was wondering how to find the line number of a line with only **commas**. The only but is that I don't know how many `commas` have each line:

Input:

```
...
Total,Total,,,
,,,,
,,,,
Alemania,,1.00,,
...
```

Thanks in advance for any clue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a single command:

```
egrep -n '^[,]+$' file
```

Line numbers will be prefixed.
Result with your provided four test lines:

```
2:,,,,
3:,,,,
```

Now, if you only want the line numbers, you can cut them easily:

```
egrep -n '^[,]+$' file | cut -d: -f1
```

Answer (score 2):

### sed

```
sed -n '/^,\+$/=' file
```

### awk

```
awk '/^,+$/&&$0=NR' file
```

Comment: **perl**: `perl -nE'say $. if /^,+$/' file` `:P`

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -nr '/^,+$/=' file
```

Output:

```
2
3
```